# How many star coins can I hold at once?

Tags: kirby-and-the-forgotten-land

What is the maximum number of star coins I can hold at once in Kirby and the Forgotten Land?

[image: star coin counter]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o6nij7ZtjJs), the maximum number is 99999 coins.
As you can see from the screenshot, collecting more coins doesn't make the counter go over that value.

[image]

Comment: Is that the maximum that can be _collected_, or just the maximum that can be _displayed_?

Comment: @IMSoP I think it's both, there's no reason to store a value that cannot be displayed

Comment: Internally, it's almost certainly stored as binary, so 99999 would be 11000011010011111; adding one gives 11000011010100000, so doesn't take up any extra space. The limit is entirely artificial, and just as easy to implement in the "display score as decimals" routine as in the "increment score" routine. I wouldn't be surprised if the counter can store any value up to 2 to the power of 31, and would then wrap around to negative numbers, if you somehow forced it that high.

Comment: @IMSoP yes, it's certainly an integer value, but it should be limited by code. In many games we have only 99 maximum lives, even if that value could reach 128, 256 or whatever.

Comment: Why "should" it be limited by code? As an example I happen to be familiar with, Sonic the Hedgehog for the Game Gear could only show 1 to 9 for the number of lives on the main game screen; it continued to count lives after that, though, and *could* show them on the level title screens. It's entirely possible Kirby is doing the same thing - continuing to count stars as you collect them, but not having anywhere on the screen to display them.

Comment: @IMSoP if that's true, that will be a very bad design choice by the developers. Old games used to do that, but nowadays showing an amount of coins/money/resources that doesn't match the stored value is a big flaw. So I'm pretty confident to claim what I wrote before.

Comment: @IMSoP it "should" be limited by code, because there will be an actual storage limit in the hardware. If it hits this hardware limit it will roll around to either 0 or a negative value. this would be an obvious bug. Since this limit must exist, it's sensible to make the limit make more sense to humans/ be nicer to the UX designers and make it limited to a certain number of decimal digits.

Comment: @pinckerman there's several reasons you'd want to display 999.. rather than the full amount. For example from a graphics design perspective it's easier to display something when you know the maximum number of digits it's going to have. It also may be a semi subtle indicator to the player that they're hoarding and there's no real value in collecting more (without "stealing" the resources from them by making it a hard cap) I think I'd probably choose to but a 99+ rather than leave it at 99 but that's ultimately an aesthetic choice. In any case I certainly wouldn't always consider it a flaw.

Comment: @Rick If the _practical_ limit that any player is likely to collect is well under 100k (bear in mind this screenshot is from a hacked game, not natural gameplay), then the possibility of them overflowing a 32-bit integer is so negligible it's barely worth the extra code to guard against it on every increment; and guarding at 2^31 would be easier than guarding at some arbitrary constant. As with Game Gear Sonic, the five digit limit might only apply to this screen, not be a global constant, and other screens - a high-score system, for instance - would be able to handle much higher values.

Comment: @Rick I used to develop games, and storing a value in a variable that doesn't match what you show on screen is wrong, in my opinion. The number is simply not incremented after it reaches the upper limit. And I agree that the maximum limit made of 9s is due to graphics design perspective.